# Salesforce Insert - Avoiding DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME errors

Tags: api, describesobject, insert

I am trying to insert Salesforce object records using APIs. Some objects throw errors with DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME errors.

Some objects have Developer Name fields:

```
2017-05-01 16:33:35,379 ERROR - UserRole record 00E46000001ABb7EAG was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:This Developer Name already exists or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name.:DeveloperName --
2017-05-01 16:35:49,856 ERROR - Folder record 00l46000001FF08AAG was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:This folder unique name already exists for this folder type or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name.:DeveloperName --
2017-05-01 16:36:18,359 ERROR - AuraDefinitionBundle record 0Ab46000000gaU1CAI was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:The Lightning Bundle name 'setStartUrl' is already defined.  Please choose a different name.:DeveloperName --
2017-05-01 16:38:50,089 ERROR - Document record 015460000019XCaAAM was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:This Document Unique Name already exists or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name.:DeveloperName --
```

Some objects do not have Developer Name fields:

```
2017-05-01 16:35:31,340 ERROR - ApexComponent record 09946000000sVHJAA2 was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:That component name is already in use or has been previously used, please choose a different one.:Name --
2017-05-01 16:33:49,407 ERROR - StaticResource record 08146000001DoVwAAK was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:That Static Resource name is already in use, please choose a different one.:Name --
2017-05-01 16:34:07,163 ERROR - ApexPage record 066460000029QZyAAM was not restored. Error message: DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME:That page name is already in use, please choose a different one.:Name --
```

What baffles is that the error code that is displayed and describessObjectResult does not mark these fields as unique. If some code has to be written on the objects that has to pre-emptively restore only the unique records, how can this be done in a more generic way rather than hardcoding based on the documentation available?

Comment: Is this a managed package developer org? That might explain the errors. Otherwise, you should be aware that DeveloperName is neither unique nor indexed, so you'd have to query the records first, and Name is indexed but not unique. This is partly because those fields are actually half of a composite key, with NamespacePrefix being the other half. I don't think you can "generically" restore them without some additional logic.

Comment: @sfdcfox I understand that it needs additional logic. Will a direct marking of any of the 'Developer Name' fields on any object as unique be a good approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where would you be marking them as unique?

Comment: There are several objects that have to be restored from one instance to a sandbox (same metadata). The objects at the destination might have existing data and thus the error I suppose. If any of the objects are checked for the presence of 'DeveloperName' field, that should be treated as a unique field in such a way that a similar operation as Upsert on 'DeveloperName' has to be performed. Isn't it? Any other objects that doesn't have the field are on a trial basis on the errors encountered and must be hardcoded in my application. Does this sound right?

Comment: What API are you using, though? If you just used the metadata API, everything should work without all the mess of whatever it is you're doing now.

Comment: SOAP API. Already created a sandbox with similar metadata and therefore Metadata API isn't required. Maybe I could explain a more robust use case: The destination sandbox is lower on space and only a set of records on a criteria (last 2 months) are restored to the sandbox. The admin creates a sandbox with the required model source metadata and copies some of the existing records (not all of them). My application should pick up the data and restore them to the destination sandbox. AFAIK, Metadata API are dealt with metadata and properties alone and not with the data. SOAP API is used here.